# How to get the file owner

Tags: c++, windows

I've been trying to obtain the file owner info (the same one displayed in Explorer) without much luck.

With the combination of `GetNamedSecurityInfo` and `LookupAccountSid` it gets me as far as `Administrators/BUILTIN`. The current active user is in the admin group too so I guess that may be the reason.

Is it possible to obtain the SID of the actual owner of the file?

Comment: The answer to this question is platform specific and differs between Windows, Linux, MacOS, UNIX & others. What platforms do you care about (besides Windows which your question seems to imply)? `stat()` is a starting point.

Comment: why you think that `Administrators/BUILTIN` not actual owner ? *Is it possible to obtain the SID of the actual owner of the file?* - very strange question. of course yes

Comment: @RbMm very strange answer for somebody who knows WinApi. Explorer shows different owner. LookupAccountSid gives me ‘Administrators/Builtin’. Why is that so?

Comment: Jesper the Q is tagged Windows and I reference Windows APIs in it. `stat` doesn’t return the owner, please see MSDN for more info.

Comment: because `Administrators/Builtin` is correct. explorer convert `Builtin` to something like `DESKTOP-xxxxxxx` which is incorrect.

Comment: @RbMm well it shows my username to me which is correct I assume?

Comment: i can not view what is explorer show to you. you get `Administrators/Builtin` - what is show "explorer" ? paste this

Comment: @RbMm, it's not uniquely Explorer that replaces "BUILTIN" in the name. It's just using the system [security editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374865) that's implemented in aclui.dll. Substituting the alias with the real domain is implemented in its `CSidCache::BuildUserList` method, which gets the system domain by querying the `PolicyAccountDomainInformation` via `LsaQueryInformationPolicy`.

Comment: Objects created by administrators are owned by "BUILTIN\Administrators" instead of the specific administrator account.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, I view this under debugger in some *DllHost.exe* process (not explorer). however I doubt - are correct replace `BUILTIN` to [Account domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721755(v=vs.85).aspx) (usually named `DESKTOP-XXXXXXX` on workstations) - are this is the same ?

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the pointer. That's something already.